# ggplot2 - Creating a graph with dot dash linetype "Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to linetype"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a graph similar to this one.

[image: Screen Shot]

But, I get the error "Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to linetype"

Here is my code:

```
combined.dframe <- data.frame(
  "Sample" = c("Share of U.S. Total Adult Population", "Share of Prison Population", 
               "Share of U.S. Total Adult Population", "Share of Prison Population", 
               "Share of U.S. Total Adult Population", "Share of Prison Population"), 
  "Race" = c("White","White", "Black", "Black", "Hispanic", "Hispanic"), 
  "Percentage" = c(60.7, 27.4, 13.4, 37.0, 18.1, 32.6))
combined.dframe$Sample <- factor(combined.dframe$Sample, 
                                 levels = c("Share of U.S. Total Adult Population", 
                                            "Share of Prison Population"))

compare.plot <- ggplot(data = combined.dframe, 
                       aes(x = Sample, y = Percentage, group = Race)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Race, linetype = 4, alpha = 1), size = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Race, alpha = 1), size = 3.15) +
  geom_text(data = combined.dframe %>% 
              filter(Sample == "Share of U.S. Total Adult Population"), 
            aes(label = paste0(Race, " - ", Percentage, "%")) , 
            hjust = 1.35, fontface = "bold", size = 3.15) +
  geom_text(data = combined.dframe %>% 
              filter(Sample == "Share of Prison Population"), 
            aes(label = paste0(Race, " - ", Percentage, "%")) , 
            hjust = -.35, fontface = "bold", size = 3.15) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  theme(panel.border     = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y     = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.y      = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.x     = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) +  
  theme(axis.ticks       = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(panel.border     = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.title       = element_text(size= 12, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(plot.subtitle       = element_text(size=7)) +
  theme(plot.caption       = element_text(size=5)) +
  labs(
    title = "Overrepresentation Of Minority Races In Prison",
    subtitle = "The racial makeup of U.S. prisons looks substantially different from the demographics of the country as a whole.",
    caption = "Source: U.S. Census Bureau, 2016"
  )
```

This is the graph without linetype.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 4):

Put the `linetype=4` argument outside the `geom_line(aes())` bit and it prints the graph with no issues and dotted lines. New code:

```
 compare.plot <- ggplot(data = combined.dframe, aes(x = Sample, y = Percentage, group = Race)) +
   geom_line(aes(color = Race, alpha = 1), size = 2, linetype = 4) +
   geom_point(aes(color = Race, alpha = 1), size = 3.15) +
   geom_text(data = combined.dframe %>% filter(Sample == "Share of U.S. Total Adult Population"), 
             aes(label = paste0(Race, " - ", Percentage, "%")) , 
             hjust = 1.35, 
             fontface = "bold", 
             size = 3.15) +
   geom_text(data = combined.dframe %>% filter(Sample == "Share of Prison Population"), 
             aes(label = paste0(Race, " - ", Percentage, "%")) , 
             hjust = -.35, 
             fontface = "bold", 
             size = 3.15) +
   theme_bw() +
   scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
   theme(panel.border     = element_blank()) +
   theme(axis.title.y     = element_blank()) +
   theme(axis.text.y      = element_blank()) +
   theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) +
   theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()) +
   theme(axis.title.x     = element_blank()) +
   theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) +  
   theme(axis.ticks       = element_blank()) +
   theme(legend.position = "none") +
   theme(panel.border     = element_blank()) +
   theme(plot.title       = element_text(size= 12, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) +
   theme(plot.subtitle       = element_text(size=7)) +
   theme(plot.caption       = element_text(size=5)) +
   labs(
     title = "Overrepresentation Of Minority Races In Prison",
     subtitle = "The racial makeup of U.S. prisons looks substantially different from the demographics of the country as a whole.",
     caption = "Source: U.S. Census Bureau, 2016"
   )
```